# Why is rails server sending GET request and i put in a POST request for form_for?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes, erb, form-for

`//sessions controller`

```
  def welcome
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to user_login_path
    end
  end
```

`//view this one doesn't work it sends a GET request`

```
 <%= form_for @user, url: create_user_session_url do |f| %>
    <div class="form_group">
      <%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Login", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

`//view one works and successfully sends POST request`

```
  <%= form_for @user, url: create_user_registration_url do |f| %>
    <div class="form_group">
      <%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <%= password_field_tag "confirm_password", nil, placeholder: "Confirm Password", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This is my form, when I do rake db:routes in console, `create_user_session` CLEARLY says its post.

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern             Controller#Action
                     root GET    /                       application#index
 create_user_registration POST   /user/login(.:format)   user/registrations#create
destroy_user_registration DELETE /user(.:format)         user/registrations#destroy
        user_registration GET    /user(.:format)         user/registrations#show
                          PATCH  /user(.:format)         user/registrations#update
                          PUT    /user(.:format)         user/registrations#update
         new_user_session GET    /user/welcome(.:format) user/sessions#welcome
      create_user_session POST   /user/session(.:format) user/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /user/logout(.:format)  user/sessions#destroy
```

HOWEVER, my stupid server thinks its sending a `GET` request, `Started GET "/user/welcome"` I'm really confused cause I have another form with the same syntax and it successfully sends a `POST` request. I don't even get any errors so it's so hard to debug.

Just incase I wasn't clear, my server does NOT even attempt to send a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the action type like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: create_user_session_url, method: :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't do anything. Server still sends GET request

Comment: can you pass in `:post` as a symbol. updated my answer

Comment: Thanks trying to help, but I figured out what was wrong. I had that form rendered into something else that made it send a get request. I tried what you did though, I didn't think about doing that to debug this.